# minimum requirements to use connect to TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to connect over http to the server where TFS is installed? 
What are the minimum tools that are required to use tfs? Team web access? team explorer?
Does he need to upgrade to vs.net 2012? Or is this not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using visual studio 2010 or 2012, no other tool is needed. just go to team explorer and enter the url of tfs.